# Drawing graph in Python with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python and also matplotlib. I tried to draw graph of equation in Python but I couldn't. Can you help me find out where I am doing wrong?

My code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotgraph ():
    T = -14
    index = 0
    ro = []
    while(T<=14):
        ro.append( 1000 - ((T-4)*(T-4)) / 180)
        T = T + 0.001
        plt.plot(ro[index],T)
        index = index +1
    return

plotgraph()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You're trying to plot 28000 points here. Does that make any sense? Apart from that you're plotting those single points as a line plot - but a line between one point is not possible, you always need at least to points to connect by a line. So the plot that is generated after 10 minutes or so (yes, creating 28000 Line2D objects takes some time) will be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you would use matplotlib to draw a line plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

T = np.linspace(-14,14, num=201)
ro = 1000 - ((T-4)*(T-4)) / 180

plt.plot(T, ro)

plt.show()
```

[image]